# Bhagavad Gita reading

Tags: puranas, bhagavad-gita

I want to know rules and precautions to take care while reading Bhagavad Gita. Also I want to know that is it good to read Bhagavad Gita on Phone digitally

Comment: 1. Read it under guidance of a guru. 2. Do not take most of the sentences literally. 3.Have an open mind. 4. Preferably read the Mahabarata. 5. Carefully choose which version of the bg you want to read (i.e. the version of srila Praphubadaba is poluted).6. The book can be read digitally.

Answer (score 2):

In one of his poems, Sri Chaitanya says: No times are set, no rites are needful, for chanting of Thy Name. The only thing needed is a desire for a pure heart and devotion. Sri Krishna says in the *Gita* Chapter 18 (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> 70. And he who will study this sacred dialogue of ours--by him shall I have been worshipped through knowledge as a sacrifice; such is My judgement.
> 71. And the man who hears this, full of faith and free from malice--even he, liberated from sin, shall attain the happy regions of the righteous.

To read the *Gita* is to worship the Lord. To read the *Gita* is to strive for the Lord. In *Gita* Chapter 6 the Lord says:

> 40. *The Lord said*: O Partha, there is no destruction for him either in this world or the next; no evil, My son, befalls a man who does good [strives for the Lord].

To start a journey, it does not matter whether you go by foot, or by car, by train by jet. The journey of a thousand miles starts with the first step. It doesn't matter if you start reading *Gita* on your phone, on paper, on parchment, or by guru. Start reading the *Gita*. The Lord Himself has said no evil befalls a man who does good.The only important thing about reading the *Gita* is to start.

Swami Vivekananda in a letter to a disciple writes (Complete Works, Vol 5, Letter XXVII, here - https://advaitaashrama.org/cw/content.php):

> Listen to an old story. A lazy tramp sauntering along the road saw an old man sitting at the door of his house and stopped to inquire of him the whereabouts of a certain place. "How far is such and such a village?" he asked. The old man remained silent. The man repeated his query several times. Still there was no answer. Disgusted at this, the traveller turned to go away. The old man then stood up and said, "The village of — is only a mile from here." "What!" said the tramp, "Why did you not speak when I asked you before?" "Because then", said the old man, "you seemed so halting and careless about proceeding, but now you are starting off in good earnest, and you have a right to an answer."
>
> Will you remember this story, my son? Go to work, the rest will come: "Whosoever not trusting in anything else but Me, rests on Me, I supply him with everything he needs" (Gitâ, IX. 22). This is no dream.

Start. Any help needed will come, from a guru or wherever.